# Drupal 7 Print block region only if page is a taxonomy page

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I just want to print my region in de page.tpl.php only if the current page is a taxonomy page.
So I need something like a check if the current page is the frontpage, but then a check for taxonomy

```
<?php 
   if(currentpage == taxonomy){
   print render($page['sidebar'])
   }
?>
```

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`arg()` function](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7) to get the underlying parts of the current page path (i.e. not the URL alias). In your case it would be like this:

```
if (arg(0) == 'taxonomy' && arg(1) == 'term') {
  print render($page['sidebar']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have more than one vocabulary, you can integrate Clive suggestion that way:

```
if (arg(0) == 'taxonomy' && arg(1) == 'term' && is_numeric(arg(2))) 
{
    $tid = (int)arg(2);
    $term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
    if($term->vocabulary_machine_name == '<YOUR_VOCABULARY_MACHINE_NAME>') print render($page['sidebar']);
}
```